# Read with C++ ifsteam from file into an template vector

Tags: c++, list, templates

I want to read from a file (**First.txt**) which looks like that:

```
1  
2 
3
```

and another file (**Second.txt**) like that:

```
ab
cd
de
```

In the main method I will call a template function to read the files like that:

```
list<string> list1;
vector<float> list2;

read(list1, "First.txt");
read(list2, "Second.txt");
```

The template function has the following structure:

```
template<typename T>
void read(T &v, string s)
{

   std::fstream f;
   f.open(dataname,std::ios_base::in);

   f.close();
}
```

Here `T` stands for the `list<string>` and `vector<float>`.
How can I read in this lists using fstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
void read(T &v, string s)
{

   std::fstream f(dataname,std::ios_base::in);
   typename T::value_type tmp;
   while( f >> tmp )
       v.push_back(tmp);

   f.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. I was not used to using value_type.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::fstream f(s,std::ios_base::in);
v.assign(std::istream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(f),
        std::istream_iterator<typename T::value_type>());
f.close();
```